# Bootstrap 3 Nav-bar change color cause showing a white border or white line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Base on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/fbqaz/). how do i remove the white line..
I tried to change the color of the nav-bar but there is a white line when its on mobile

[image]

on the bootstrap-theme.css
i have added and editted some codes

Code added and editted on bootstrap theme

```
.navbar {
  /*
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 0%, left 100%, from(#3B5998), to(#f8f8f8));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3B5998, 0%, #f8f8f8, 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3B5998 0%, #f8f8f8 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3B5998 0%, #f8f8f8 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff8f8f8', GradientType=0);
  */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff3B5998', endColorstr='#fff8f8f8', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(59,89,152, 0.15), 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(59,89,152, 0.15), 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);

  border-radius: 4px; 
  background-color:#3B5998; 
}

.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus  {
  background-color: #3B5998;
  color:#e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  /*text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);*/ 
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a  {
  color: #ffffff;
} 

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus ,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
} 

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret{
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #3B5998;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #3B5998;
  border-bottom-color: #3B5998;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to fix top border of `.navbar-collapse` (it's Bootstrap's `#e6e6e6` border color you see):

```
.navbar-default div.navbar-collapse
{
    border-top:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

After disabling it with `border-top:none` you will still notice a slightly dim line which is because there is a `box-shadow` rule, you need to override it too with `box-shadow:none`.

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/ZfYNG/

In this fiddle you will find 2 ways of fixing top border - by setting its color to `#3b5998` and completely disabling it.

Answer (score 5):

Nice found the issue

```
.navbar-collapse{
border-top:0px !important;
 box-shadow:none;
}
```

after animation it adds a border top

wait ill give  a fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFVHJ/)