# Bootstrap:where does this white line come from?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Warning: Bootstrap and HTML5 novice here.

I'm designing a header for a site with two rows: first, there's the logo, and then, in another row, a navigation bar. Things work, more or less... except that there is a thin white line between the two rows that I have no way of removing. Here's my code:

```
<header class='masthead'>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
</header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
* html5doctor.com Reset v1.6.1 - http://cssreset.com */
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,var,b,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}body{line-height:1}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}nav ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}a{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}ins{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;text-decoration:none}mark{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold}del{text-decoration:line-through}abbr[title],dfn[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}hr{display:block;height:1px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #ccc;margin:1em 0;padding:0}input,select{vertical-align:middle}


body{
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
}


/*---------------------HEADER-------------*/
header.masthead{
    background-color: #103961;
    height: 82px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

header.masthead nav{
    background: #339966;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar-brand>img{
    width: 270px;
}

.navbar {
    background: #003471;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    min-height: 35px;
}

.navbar-nav{
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.navbar-nav li a{
    color:white !important;
    text-shadow: none;
    background:none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Under Bootstrap 3.3.1, and in Firefox 33 and Safari 6 (for desktop both), I get a thin white line between both rows:

[image: screencap. Can you see the white line?]

And I have no idea where it comes from. All possible margins, paddings, borders... are set to 0px (well, except `border-image-width`, which shows up as 1, but setting it explicitly to 0 does nothing.

Comment: Can't reproduce the bug in FF

Comment: Not sure if you need the reset as Bootstrap already has its own

Comment: Seems to run fine when I pop your code into Bootply and run it in Chrome. http://www.bootply.com/9Fx2cYWuiE

Comment: Looks fine to me as well FF 34...are you sure you aren't zoomed or something weird like that?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded. As it turns out, after I posted the question I started learning to use jsFiddle and Bootply, and couldn't reproduce it there... but I could see it clearly in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044657/bootstrap-3-nav-bar-change-color-cause-showing-a-white-border-or-white-line?rq=1 gave me a hint, but I had to modify the accepted answer there: instead of removing the `box-shadow` in `.navbar-default div.navbar-collapse`, I just did it in `.navbar-default`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. All you need to do is adjust the border for your navbar (be sure to use the !important text).

You can do it by using the following CSS:

```
.navbar {
border: 0 !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!